# How to animate multiple paths in sequence in Android canvas?

Tags: java, android, android-animation, android-canvas

I want to animate multiple paths in sequence, for example, I have

Path[] line and Path[] circle

so when I do for example

```
   line[0].moveTo(x, y);

   graphPath[j].lineTo(x, y);
```

I want to animate this part first and when 
                   finish I want to add circle in same x,y postion

```
   circle[0].addCircle(x, y, 10, Path.Direction.CW);
```

what I have done so far inside onDraw()

```
    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

            for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
                if (dataPoints2[j] != null) {
                    float x = leftPadding;
                    float y = height * getDataPoint(0, j) + topPadding;

                    graphPath[j].moveTo(x, y);
                    circlePath[j].addCircle(x, y, 10, Path.Direction.CW);

                    for (int i = 1; i < dataPoints2[j].size(); i++) {
                        x = width * (((float) i ) / dataPoints2[j].size()) + leftPadding;
                        y = height * getDataPoint(i, j) + topPadding;

                        graphPath[j].lineTo(x, y);
                        circlePath[j].addCircle(x, y, 10, Path.Direction.CW);
                    }
                }
            }

            PathMeasure measure = new PathMeasure(graphPath[0], false);
            length = measure.getLength();
            ObjectAnimator animator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(Chart.this, "phase", 1.0f, 0.0f);
            animator.setDuration(8000);
            animator.start();

        for (int j = 0; j < graphPath.length; j++) {
            canvas.drawPath(graphPath[j], linePaint[j]);
            canvas.drawPath(circlePath[j], circlePaint[j]);
        }
         }
public void setPhase(float phase){
    linePaint[0].setPathEffect(createPathEffect(length, phase, 0.0f));
    invalidate();
}
private static PathEffect createPathEffect(float pathLength, float phase, float offset)
{
    return new DashPathEffect(new float[] { pathLength, pathLength },
            Math.max(phase * pathLength, offset));
}
```

this will draw the circle then animate the line connecting the circle points 
what I need is to animate the line and draw circle when the line reaches every x,y points